# Deleting records in relationships AFTER the transaction

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables - *books* and *books_authors* with relationship between *books_authors.user_id* and *books.id* columns with flag *ON DELETE CASCADE*.

I've got also mechanism to import data to DB from XML files and the problem is, when I want to reload whole *books* table with new data, all records in *books_authors* dissapear, even the relationship actually exsits. The MySQL code of this mechanism looks like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE * FROM books;
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
...
COMMIT;
```

After this transaction, I've got *books* table with new data, but *books_authors* table is empty.

**Can I do anything to tell MySQL, to check relationships AFTER the transaction?**

Comment: Remove that `ON DELETE CASCADE` which is why books_authors table is getting empty. Either make `ON DELETE NO ACTION` (OR) drop the constraint and after importing data recreate the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the delete on the `books` table to cascade to `books_authors`, then you need to temporarily disable the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` session variable.

Then if you want to delete the orphaned records after re-inserting into the books table, you can do so with the multi-table delete syntax and an outer join.

Something like this should work:

```
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DELETE * FROM books;
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
...

delete      c.*
from        books_authors c
left join   books p
on          c.book_id=p.id
where       p.id is null;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is copying all of your records from books_authors to a temporary table, delete all your books, insert the updated ones, and then restore the books_authors records with a join between books_authors_tmp and books (so only existing book relations will be restored). Something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS books_authors_tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books_authors_tmp 
AS (SELECT * FROM books_authors);

DELETE * FROM books;
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT books (...) VALUES (...);
...

INSERT INTO books_authors
SELECT bat.*
FROM books b
INNER JOIN books_authors_tmp bat
ON
    b.id = bat.bookId;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS books_authors_tmp;

COMMIT;
```